# 'ruby' was not found, cannot install rubygems unless ruby is present

Tags: ruby, rvm

I installed `RVM` on my Ubuntu, and when I try to install `Ruby`, I get this error.

```
rvm install 2.0.0
# 'ruby' was not found, cannot install rubygems unless ruby is present (Do you have an RVM ruby installed & selected?)
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a known bug https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2382

Click the `Watch` button on bottom of the page - or comment if you can provide more details.

This bug was fixed, a new stable version is released: `1.24.6`.

Comment: This is fixed as of 5 mins ago. Run 'rvm get head' then try again